# Why is python writing to my CSV file in eastern characters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Maybe I'm being stupid and missing something, I don't have a lot of experience with  using CSV files however I have a filer that simply reads:
Name    Coder-ID    Certificate Type

And I want to convert the text into a new file like so:
Name", "Coder-ID", "Certificate Type

However it converts it like this:
NameⰢ∠䌀漀搀攀爀ⴀ䤀䐀∀‬"Certificate Type

My Code is:

```
import csv

#File Setup
def setup():
    userAnswers = open('My Report.csv', 'r+')
    userAnswers2 = open('My ReportNew.csv', 'w')

    for line in userAnswers:
        userAnswers2.write(line.replace('\t', '", "' ))


#Set up Run
setup()
```

PS: The words ARE tabbed apart but this site doesnt seem to let me tab words in my post. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Can't tell if you're using Python 3 or not, might be an encoding issue

Comment: @yorodm I am using Python 3.5, and how would you suggest fixing it?

Comment: Try passing the `encoding` keyword parameter to `open`. Just to make sure they're both using UTF-8.

Comment: @yorodm  UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte     I dont know whats happening lmao

Comment: @yorodm utf-16 worked!

Comment: Check the file with a hex viewer. That first byte you got must have been part of a [BOM](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html).

Answer (score 0):

So you want to convert from tabs to quoted fields with commas?

```
import csv

with open('input.csv','r',newline='') as inf,open('output.csv','w',newline='') as outf:
    r = csv.reader(inf,delimiter='\t')
    w = csv.writer(outf,quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    for line in r:
        w.writerow(line)
```

Input (tab-delimited):

```
Name    Coder-ID Certificate Type
Mark    abc      abcdef      1
Mark    abc      abcdef      1
Mark    abc      abcdef      1
```

Output:

```
"Name","Coder-ID","Certificate Type"
"Mark","abc","abcdef","1"
"Mark","abc","abcdef","1"
"Mark","abc","abcdef","1"
```

If you still have trouble with encoding specify the encoding of the file explicitly in the `open` statement with `encoding='utf8'` parameter (or whatever the actual encoding is).